# Redux-reducer not getting called

Tags: redux

I'm trying to learn Redux. I'm trying a test app and I'm stuck on this error and have no idea why the reducer isn't updating the state. I've looked at the common problems that cause this and can't seem to find those errors in mine, my reducer doesn't change the state

```
    logItem.js
    import React from 'react';
    import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
    import {connect} from 'react-redux';
    import {addCurrent} from '../../actions/logAction';
    
    const LogItem = (props) => {
        const {message, tech, date, attention} = props.singleLog;
    
        console.log(props.currentLog)
    
        const updateLog = (singleLog) => {  
            updateLog(singleLog, singleLog._id)
        }
    
        const current = (singleLog) => {
            console.log(singleLog)
            addCurrent(singleLog)
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>{message}</h3>
                <p className={`text ${attention}`}>was last updated by {tech} on {date}</p> 
                <Link onClick={() => current(props.singleLog)} to='/addLog'>update</Link>
                <button>delete</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
        currentLog : state.log.current
    })
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, {addCurrent})(LogItem);
```

**logaction.js**

```
export const addCurrent = (singleLog) => {
    console.log(singleLog)
    return({type: SET_CURRENT, payload: singleLog})
}


import { SET_LOADING, GET_LOGS, LOGS_ERROR, ADD_LOG, UPDATE_LOG, SET_CURRENT } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    logs: null,
    loading: true,
    current: null,
    errors: null
}
```

**logReducer.js**

```
import { SET_LOADING, GET_LOGS, LOGS_ERROR, ADD_LOG, UPDATE_LOG, SET_CURRENT } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    logs: null,
    loading: true,
    current: null,
    errors: null
}
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log(action.type)
    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_CURRENT: 
            console.log("5")
            console.log(action.payload)
                return {
                    ...state,
                    current: action.payload,
                    errors:null
            }
        default: 
        return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your reducer looks fine, are you sure it's executed? What do the redux devtools say?

Comment: I tried console.log in  the reducer as well to see if it is working but its not. redux dev tools shows no change in state as well...is there a  way to find the issue...thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your action does not get dispatched, not sure why you claim the reducer doesn't do anything when obviously the action isn't even getting dispatched. Please use redux devtools next time so you at least know what's going on and can articulate a better question.

You should replace `addCurrent(singleLog)` with `props.addCurrent(singleLog)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
export const addCurrent = (singleLog) => {
    console.log(singleLog)
    return({type: SET_CURRENT, payload: singleLog})
}
```

with

```
export const addCurrent = (singleLog) => dispatch => {
    console.log(singleLog)
    dispatch({type: SET_CURRENT, payload: singleLog})
}
```

Comment: I gave a try with your code @jun..but didn't work for me..is there any other way u think I can fix this...thanks anyways